# Continuing ternary operator ?: on next line

Tags: awk

I am using the following ternary operator `?:`.

```
rl = globrl == 1 ? "?([-+])*([" dgt "])?([.,])+([" dgt "])"
                 : "^[-+]?[" dgt "]*[.,]?[" dgt "]+$"
```

Looks that awk does not allow continuing the ternary operator an a new line.

Comment: See [awk Statements Versus Lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Statements_002fLines)

Comment: How have I never stumbled into that rabbit-hole in 30+ years ?

Comment: I am always trouble !

Answer (score 1):

The Awk grammar is whitespace-sensitive. Effectively, the newline character is a token in the grammar, rather than disappearing whitespace.

However, Awk also supports backslash line continuations, similarly to the C preprocessor, shell and `make`:

```
rl = globrl == 1 ? "?([-+])*([" dgt "])?([.,])+([" dgt "])" \
                 : "^[-+]?[" dgt "]*[.,]?[" dgt "]+
```

Comment: Nobody answered this since March? This site is dead.

Comment: Kaz no, not dead. Maybe the question simply got lost